# Are "begin" and "end" reserved words or not?

Tags: ruby

I'm kind of confused about reserved words in Ruby.

"The Ruby Programming Language", co-authored by Matz, says that `begin` and `end` are reserved words of the language. They're certainly used syntactically to mark out blocks.

However, range objects in the language have methods named `begin` and `end`, as in

```
(1..10).end
=> 10
```

Now, testing this out, I find that, indeed, I can define methods named "begin" and "end" on objects, though if I try to name a variable "begin" it fails. (Here's a sample of using it as a method name, it actually works...:)

```
class Foo
  def begin
    puts "hi"
  end
end

Foo.new.begin
```

So, I suppose I'm asking, what actually is the status of reserved words like this? I would have imagined that they couldn't be used for method names (and yet it seems to work) or that at the very least it would be terrible style (but it is actually used in the core language for the Range class).

I'm pretty confused as to when they're allowed to be used and for what. Is there even documentation on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they are reserved words. Yes, they can be used for method names. No, you can't call them without an explicit receiver. It's probably not a good idea anyway.

```
class Foo
  def if(foo)
    puts foo
  end
end

Foo.new.if("foo") # outputs foo, returns nil
```

**Update:** Here's a quote from "The Ruby Programming Language", by Matz (the creator of Ruby) himself:

> In most languages, these words would be called “reserved words” and
>   they would be never allowed as identifiers. The Ruby parser is
>   flexible and does not complain if you prefix these keywords with @,
>   @@, or $ prefixes and use them as instance, class, or global variable
>   names. Also, you can use these keywords as method names, with the
>   caveat that the method must always be explicitly invoked through an
>   object.

Comment: Is this true for all "reserved words"? If it is bad style, why does the core API do it? (Though intuitively it seems like awful style -- indeed, an awful thing for the language to permit at all.) And, *is this documented*?

Comment: It's permitted because sometimes having methods called like a reserved word may make sense (IMHO `Range#end`) is a good example. Things aren't always black and white, like most features this might be helpful when used with care. As for documentation, a quick Google search turned up http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_syntax.htm, which states that "[t]hese reserved words may not be used as constant or variable names. They can, however, be used as method names", which IMHO makes perfect sense.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be official documentation though. (I haven't found any mention about it in official documents, though that does not imply that it doesn't exist.)

Comment: Ah, very cool. I don't suppose you could edit that to list the page it is on?

Comment: (It appears to be on page 31...)

Comment: Why isn't this a good idea? I think it is an awesome feature. If the parser can tell the difference, why should it be discouraged?

Comment: @Perry, it seems simple enough: `if` is a reserved keyword, `@if` is an instance variable, `@@if` is a class variable, `$if` is a global variable and `object.if` is a method. `:)` I think any Ruby programmer would be able to deduce the meaning of these expressions.

Comment: This is perhaps a matter of taste or age, but my ability to remember numerous rules is limited. The more rules you add, the harder it is to recall all of them. I know and have to use a dozen programming languages fairly regularly, and I no longer have the memory I did at 25, so after a while this sort of thing becomes more a bother than a help. Of course, some people have different tastes -- to each his own.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira As I said in my other comment, "helpful when used with care". I think `Range#end` for example makes perfect sense, but then you have to remember to call it with `self.end` inside the class where it's defined, unlike other methods that don't need the explicit receiver.

Answer (score 2):

When they are given in a form that is unambiguously a method call, you can use them. If you have a period in front of it `.begin` or have parentheses after is `begin()`, then it is unambiguously a method call. When you try to use it as a variable `begin`, it is ambiguous (in principle).

Actually, as Perry, notes, `begin()` might be tricky. I checked with irb with Ruby 1.9.3, and the following strange thing happens:

```
irb(main):001:0> def begin(foo)
irb(main):002:1> puts 'a'
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> begin(3)
irb(main):005:1> 
irb(main):006:1* end
=> 3
```

It is not defined, and what looks like a method call might be just a block returning the last-evaluated `3`. But the lines around `def begin(foo)` remains mystery.

Comment: Your claim about parentheses seems to be false, at least in Ruby 1.9.3 -- begin() does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @sawa Nothing strange here. The parenthesis are interpreted as — unnecessary — parenthesis around the block's body. That's why the 3 gets returned as is. Wy the first definition is a mistery I don't understand, all method definitions return `nil` and `self.methods.grep(/beg/) #=> [:begin]`. If you just type `send(:begin)` in IRB, it will work.

Comment: @MichaelKohl What is defined in the definition starting with `def begin(foo)`?

Comment: @sawa: What's always defined when you define a method in IRB, an instance method of `main`, that's why `self.methods` will list it.